# Find the longest non-palindromic substring in a string

Tags: string, algorithm, palindrome

I need to find out the longest non-palindromic substring ( a string which itself isn't a palindrome, doesn't matter whether any substring of it is) in a string, in O(n**2) or less time.

I can come up with the simple brute force algorithm, finding all possible substrings (O(n ** 2)), then for each such substring checking if that is a palindrome (O(n)), taking the overall complexity to O(n**3).

There are O(n**2) variants of finding out longest palindromic substring and sequence, but I am unable to reuse them to find out the solution here.

How do I do it in O(n**2) time?

Comment: Hint: if you remove the first character from a palindrome, you get something that isn't a palindrome - except for one very specific family of cases that is easy to detect.

Comment: What is a non-palindromic substring? A substring that isn't itself a full palindrome? Because in that case the problem sounds pretty simple. Try to work it out on paper with a few examples.

Comment: Edited question. Yes Jan, I know. The specific set is what that is bothering me.

Comment: Why's that specific set bothering you? Tell me, what do you think the set is?

Comment: As far as I can see, there are variety of ways I can get a non-palindromic substring from the longest palindromic one - adding characters at the beginning or at the end, removing characters from the beginning within, or from the end, or doing both. Can't figure out.

Comment: Don't start with the longest palindromic substring, that just complicates things. Jan Dvorak hints at a simple way to solve this in O(n).

Comment: More specifically, it's O(1) in the average case.

Comment: @JanDvorak First you need to check whether the original string is a palindrome, that's `O(n)`

Comment: Original string is not a palindrome, we cannot rely on it being a palindrome.

Comment: @AttitudeMonger If your original string isn't a palindrome, the solution is trivial: your answer is the string itself. So let's assume it is a palindrome. What properties must this palindrome have to still stay a palindrome after you removed the first letter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there's an answer posted already, let me turn my hints into an actual answer:

First, check if the full string is:

- a palindrome (O(n), with O(1) average case)
- a repetition of the same character, such as "aaaaaaaaaaaa" (done in the same loop).

Then:

- if the string isn't a palindrome, the longest non-palindrome substring is the string itself
- if the string is a palindrome but not a repetition of the same character, then removing either end will make it a non-palindrome, and the longest such substring
- if the string is a repetition of the same character, then it has no non-palindrome substring. Alternatively, depending on your definition of palindrome, the only non-palindrome substring is the empty substring.

Comment: Hmm right. That looks pretty complete. Let me see if there is any case missing.

Answer (score -2):

Let s,e be positions in the strings.

You can tell if the substring s,e is palindrom by checks `string[s] == string[e]` and the substring s+1, e-1 is also palindrom (special case single chars `s==e` and empty strings`s>e` to true).

So the easiest implementation is to make a recursive function as described above and memoize the results (store them in a external matrix).

You can also do it iteratively if you are careful with your iteration (so that you only need results previously computed).

Both will populate O(N^2) and the individual computations are trivial.